# Select all row in table from name table is Nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, dynamicquery

I will create procedure by SQL query and have `@name_table` (`nvarchar`).

How do one procedure using for multiple table not use `EXEC`?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_produces
(
   id int primary key,
   name nvarchar(250)
)
GO

INSERT INTO tbl_produces VALUES (1, 'abc'), (2, 'cde'), (3, 'hfd')
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE return_table
(
   @table_name nvarchar(250)
)
AS
  SELECT * FROM @table_name  
  RETURN
  GO

EXEC return_table 'tbl_produces' " = " SELECT * FROM tbl_produces
```

"

How can I do that? Help me! Thanks for help

I don't want use

```
CREATE PROCEDURE return_table
(
   @table_name_ nvarchar(250)
)
AS
  DECLARE @sqlStr nvarchar(max) ,
          @ParmDefinition nvarchar(MAX) 
  Set @sqlStr = 'SELECT * FROM @table_name' 
  SET @ParmDefinition = N'@table_name nvarchar(250),
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlStr,
                        @ParmDefinition,
                        @table_name = @table_name_
  RETURN
  GO
```

I want not use EXECUTE can return table

---

Can see if you use query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE return_table
(
   @table_name_ nvarchar(250)
)
AS
  DECLARE @sqlStr nvarchar(max) ,
          @ParmDefinition nvarchar(MAX) 
  Set @sqlStr = 'SELECT * FROM @table_name' 
  SET @ParmDefinition = N'@table_name nvarchar(250),
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlStr,
                        @ParmDefinition,
                        @table_name = @table_name_
  RETURN
  GO
```

for multiple table when i want create 1 function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DanhSachNhaCungCap] ( ) -- Thong Tin Nha Cung Cap
RETURNS  TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
    select * from 
    ( 
       SELECT 'EXEC return_table ''tblProduct_01''' AS sp_executesql
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT 'EXEC return_table ''tblProduct_02''' AS sp_executesql     
    ) AS T
)
GO
```

-> it is fails

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: It looks like a puzzle to me.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the question is : how can I do dynamic SQL without doing dynamic SQL.

Comment: I want i can use table_name (nvarchar) for PROCEDURE can select all rows in this table

Comment: Without dynamic query it's not possible as From keyword accepts a database object not just a string as you want to supply as procedure input variable.

Comment: yes. I using many query select for many table. i don't want use exce for return table in procedure and function. 1 one function and procedure can return multiple table and can use for select in other function with other table

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_produces
(
   id int primary key,
   name nvarchar(250)
)
GO

INSERT INTO tbl_produces VALUES (1, 'abc'), (2, 'cde'), (3, 'hfd')
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE return_table
(
   @table_name nvarchar(250)
)
AS
  DECLARE @V_Query NVARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @V_Query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name;

  EXEC sp_executesql @V_Query
  GO

EXEC return_table 'tbl_produces'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `sp_executesql`?

```
sp_executesql 'select * from ' + @tableName
```

[Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)